# using quartz in a web app with spring

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I've created a small console application to see how quartz work and it was easy to create an `applicationcontext` object inside the main method to get the cron run. OK now I'm in a real project managed by maven and which is using cron jobs defined in some of the modules. Each of the module has his own spring config file. I had 3 of the modules  using quartz so it was setup in each of the spring config file. The web app module is the one who has the dependency of each of the modules.

Now i had few concerns:

1. should I created the `applicationcontext` as in the console project or it's supposed to be loaded. If yes, where am I supposed to load it.
2. based on research on the Internet I did on line I use  `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` for easy unit testing. And now that I have to use the `CronExpression` class to test the `getNextValidTimeAfter`, I still don't know how to organize it properly

Can anyone give me a hand. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comment, the question is closer to "How to load Spring application context file(s) for a Web application".

According to [Section 3.8.5, "Convenient ApplicationContext instantiation for web applications"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/beans.html#context-create), you can register an `ApplicationContext` using the `ContextLoaderListener` as follows (add this to your `web.xml` file):

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- or use the ContextLoaderServlet instead of the above listener
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
-->
```

Comment: pascal i really appreciate your effort but i don't think you 've understood me.English not being my language.right now i don't have any problem wiring the bean and the trigger and the schedulerfactorybean since i've done it already for my console project.what i meant was that now that i'm in a web application and that i don't have the java main method to call the applicationcontext object in, i'm lost about how to go about it in a wep app environment.i edited the post i was writing getNextValidTimeAfter not getNext. thanks

Comment: pascal i start to see the light now.One concern.if i go by the listener , i'll just have to write all the applicaitoncontexts inside the param-value right?but the application contexts are in different modules so in my case the using the servlet is suitable.correct me if i'm wrong.and thank you very very much

Comment: Filter or Servlet, you have to declare the `<context-param>` in both cases, this part doesn't change. Then, in order to allow Spring to find the application context files, you just need to put them on the classpath of the webapp (i.e. the modules need to be packaged in the WEB-INF/lib directory). But this should already be the case.

Comment: thanks you so much for your help.i found that all the other maven module applicationcontext should be available in the web-app /META-INF so i'll just add to the existing webappcontext those like `<context-param>/WEB-INF/webappcontext.xml module1contextxml module2context.xml</context-param>`. thanks do you have any idea about the unit testing

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you want to "unit" test. `CronExpression#getNextValidTimeAfter(java.util.Date)` is a method from the Quartz API and is a supposed to be working.